# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where' for dense_rank()

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

```
select * from (select e.*, dense_rank() over (order by salary desc) as rk from employee e) 
where rk>=5
```

I got a syntax error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

What's the problem?

Comment: subqueries in `from` have to be given an alias.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks, but not very clear on what you mean, and how should I form the right syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
select * from (select e.*, 
                      dense_rank() over (order by salary desc) as rk 
               from employee e
               ) tmp  --alias to from subquery
where tmp.rk>=5
```

hope this help!